# How to implement WSO2 Data Analytics Server (DAS)

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-bam

I would like to know if anyone of you has implemented WSO2 DAS in some scenario. Any tutorial (step by step) that you have, will be helpfull.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone through [WSO2 DAS documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/About+DAS)? It's really hard to understand your requirements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Sorry for not be too specific, I've been reading WSO2 DAS documentation, but it's quite difficult to apply in my scenario. My scenario how to capture data (info) from Palo Alto Networks, Switches Cisco and Server Log and by using DAS generate dashboards in management level to take opportunity decisions. Do you have any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2DAS specifically doesn't support monitoring. But There is a way that you can use WSO2DAS for monitoring logs and other application status.

You can create a DAS stream and analyze log data. After that using the dashboard creation tool available in WSO2DAS you will be able to create dashboard to show the analyzed data.

You can find an example from following non-official blog post.

http://supunsetunga.blogspot.com/2016/03/creating-log-dashboard-with-wso2-das.html

For real time analysis you can create external publisher to publish data in to a DAS stream and continue analysis from there. External publisher will be the data source for DAS as it was a log file in the example explained in the above mentioned blog post. Please refer to DAS documentation mentioned below.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Publishing+Data+to+DAS

Also WSO2DAS has Email Publisher which send an email on an event. You can use this to alert specific user about a exception or any other thing. Please refer following documentation for more details.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Email+Event+Publisher

Hope this will help you.